# Check if the Enter key is pressed in a linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to check if the value entered by the user using the `read` command is the *Enter* key using `if/elif` statements in order to `echo` something. How should I do?

Comment: i've tried to check "\n" if entered but it did'nt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\n` at the end of the user's input is stripped off before assigning the value to the shell variable.  If the user just presses `ENTER`, the value read will be the empty string.

```
read VAR
if [[ -z $VAR ]]; then echo "User pressed ENTER with no input text"; fi
```

Comment: Also it is worth unsetting $IFS variable. Without it the code above can run on spaces not just \n.